# Principal Component Regression on log returns exactly predicting last value of time series every time

Tags: regression, time-series, pca, python, scikit-learn

I am trying to run PCR on a list of a few time series, and no matter which dates I run this on, I am getting a difference between my predicted and actual of zero for the last entry in every time series.  To explain that in more detail, I'm running the following Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def rich_cheap_pcr_between_dates(df, dependent_col, n_components=3, start="", end=""):
    # Preprocess data
    df = slice_df_between_dates(df, start, end)
    df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)
    y = df[dependent_col]
    X = df.drop(dependent_col, 1)

    # Get log returns of X Dataframe
    x_scaled = X.pct_change(periods=1).dropna()
    x_scaled = x_scaled + 1
    x_scaled = x_scaled.apply(np.log)

    # Get log returns of y Dataframe
    y_scaled = y.pct_change(periods=1).dropna()
    y_scaled = y_scaled + 1
    y_scaled = y_scaled.apply(np.log)

    # PCA
    pca = PCA(n_components=n_components)
    X_reduced = pca.fit_transform(x_scaled)

    # Linear Regression on principal components
    regr = LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(X_reduced, y_scaled)

    # Prediction and richness/cheapness to actual
    pcr_predicted = regr.predict(X_reduced)
    rich_cheap = y_scaled - pcr_predicted

    plt.plot(y_scaled.index, y_scaled.cumsum())
    plt.plot(y_scaled.index, pcr_predicted.cumsum())

symbols_list = ['ORCL', 'TSLA', 'IBM','YELP', 'MSFT']
d = {}
for ticker in symbols_list:
    d[ticker] = DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", '2014-12-01')
pan = pd.Panel(d)
df = pan.minor_xs('Adj Close')

rich_cheap_pcr_between_dates(df, "IBM", start="01/01/16", end="07/29/16")
```

Where `pcr_predicted` is the predicted daily log returns of the data series based on the PCR, and `rich_cheap` is the difference between that and the actual log returns of the series.  The strange part that I can't figure out is, no matter which data series I run this on, I continue to get the same exact final values for `pcr_predicted.cumsum()` and `y_scaled.cumsum()`.  Or, in other words, when I ran this for the above code, I got a graph that looks like this:

[image: IBM]

Here's the same code run but with `IBM` replaced by `ORCL`:

[image: ORCL]

Notice that the two values fluctuate around each other, but then converge to the same value at the very end.  Now, no matter what I choose as my starting and ending dates or time series, I see the same phenomenon, with the last values converging to the same thing.  This isn't what I would expect, unless I am doing something in my code that's forcing that to happen.  Can anyone help me figure out what's causing this behavior?

Comment: Cross posting is generally considered a bad thing so it is probably better to delete one. The issue seems to be to be statistical so I would suggest to keep this and remove the other

Comment: On the pictures it looks like the 1st value is also coinciding; does it always happen too?